# Problem when taking a photo with the camera

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a problem when dragging an image from the camera and making it wallpaper to ImageView. 
I used the following code and it works on versions less than 5 .
But versions 5 or higher code does not work permanently and the camera does not work at all

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.camera_capimage" android:grantUriPermissions="true"  android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true"  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

       public static Bitmap bitmap;
        public static string fileName;
        public ImageView _imageView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

            button.Click += BtnCamera_Click;

        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
            _imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

error message

Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera } from ProcessRecord{273b163 23970:com.companyname.camera_capimage/u0a98} (pid=23970, uid=10098) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA'

Comment: I test the code you provided on Android 6.0, it works well. You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/5L7USVX I test on without permission request.

Comment: Any update? Have you check the screenshot?

Comment: thanks  Wendy Zang

Comment: Have you solved the problem?